# Redux Toolkit - How useSelector is referring to initialState through reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to understand (ineffectively) how does useSelector refers to initialState stored in Slice with the line `const count = useSelector((state) => state.counter.value)`

Referring to documentation, where this is Slice:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
  value: 0,
}

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      // Redux Toolkit allows us to write "mutating" logic in reducers. It
      // doesn't actually mutate the state because it uses the Immer library,
      // which detects changes to a "draft state" and produces a brand new
      // immutable state based off those changes
      state.value += 1
    },
    decrement: (state) => {
      state.value -= 1
    },
    incrementByAmount: (state, action) => {
      state.value += action.payload
    },
  },
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions

export default counterSlice.reducer
```

And this is store:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import counterReducer from '../features/counter/counterSlice'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    counter: counterReducer,
  },
})
```

In Component Counter I'm trying to access the initialState:

```
...
export function Counter() {
  const count = useSelector((state) => state.counter.value)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  return (
    <div>
     ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

so how does const count = useSelector((state) => state.counter.value) refer to initialState of slice if in counterSlice by default I export only reducer object?

`export default counterSlice.reducer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exported `reducer` object is not the same as the `reducers` property you provide to `createSlice`. The function `createSlice` does a lot of magic behind the scene that you can read more in RTK's source here:
[createSlice](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/master/packages/toolkit/src/createSlice.ts) and [createReducer](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/master/packages/toolkit/src/createReducer.ts).

**TL;DR:** `createSlice` passes the provided `initialState` to a function `createReducer` like this:

```
createReducer(options.initialState, (builder) => {
  // Some code
}
```

And then `createReducer` attaches the `initialState` to the `reduce` like this:

```
if (isStateFunction(initialState)) {
  getInitialState = () => freezeDraftable(initialState())
} else {
  const frozenInitialState = freezeDraftable(initialState)
  getInitialState = () => frozenInitialState
}

// Some code

reducer.getInitialState = getInitialState
```

With that, the `store` can get the `initialState`.